Symfony 2.8 containerize
I'm trying to containerize a Symfony Application, Before that, I used it via ssh, but in order to optimize, I'm trying to upload a Docker container, but I don't know what settings are needed for Apache
Dockerfile:
FROM php:7.0-apache

# Update stretch repositories
RUN sed -i -e 's/deb.debian.org/archive.debian.org/g' \
           -e 's|security.debian.org|archive.debian.org/|g' \
           -e '/stretch-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list

# Install and configure some project requirements
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        apt-utils \
        libpng-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        git \
        unzip \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        g++

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

# Install XPDF and QPDF dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y cmake libqpdf-dev libqt4-dev qt4-qmake
RUN apt-get install -y python3 && cp /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

# Copy binaries to /tmp
COPY ./.docker/binaries/*.tar.gz /tmp/

# Set working directory to /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp

# Install XPDF dependency - Freetype
RUN tar -xf freetype-2.13.1.tar.gz && cd freetype-2.13.1 && ./configure && make && make install

# Install XPDF
RUN tar -xf xpdf-4.00.tar.gz && cd xpdf-4.00 && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Releas -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/xpdf && make && make install
RUN tar -xf xpdf-tools-linux-4.04.tar.gz && mv xpdf-tools-linux-4.04 /usr/local/bin/xpdf-tools-linux-4.00

# Install QPDF
RUN tar -xf qpdf-8.0.2.tar.gz && cd qpdf-8.0.2 && ./configure && make && make install
RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Set working directory back to /
WORKDIR /

# Cleanup /tmp
RUN rm -rdf /tmp/*

# Copy the custom configuration files
COPY ./.docker/apache2/sites-available/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY ./.docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

# Copy application files
COPY . /var/www/html

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Setup files permissions
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/web/ && chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/web/
RUN chmod -R 777 -R app/cache/

# Enable apache2 rewrite module
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Set apache user
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Set the default command to run when starting the container
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

Docker compose:
version: '3.7'

services:
  alow:
    environment:
      - COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
      - PHP_EXTENSION_XDEBUG=1
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./.docker/apache2/logs:/var/log/apache2
      - ./config/parameter.yml:/app/config/parameter.yml 
    ports:
      - '8001:80'
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    external: true

the container is running, but it says not found on the page


Do I need to configure something to have access to my routes?

Put a test.txt in the public directory. If you cannot call it with /test.txt, it is an Apache configuration problem. If so, the .htaccess may not be analysed or something is wrong with Symfony.

The problem was the web folder, thx
